# How to resolve " driver failed programming external connectivity" in docker-compose?

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-compose

I am using docker@19.03.2 build 6a30dfc) and docker-compose@1.19.0, build 9e633ef.

Given a `docker-compose.yml` (that used to work fine for a very long time and was unchanged since April 2019) file that only spins up a mariadb container and is supposed to expose the mysql port to the host:

```
pe-db:
    image: mariadb:10.3
    ports:
        - 3306:3306
    environment:
        MYSQL_DATABASE: dev_db
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
        MYSQL_USER: dev
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root_password
```

yet when running:

```
 docker-compose up
```

I am getting the error message:

```
Recreating fcac8d931b6a_ratepipeline_pe-db_1 ... error

ERROR: for fcac8d931b6a_ratepipeline_pe-db_1  Cannot start service pe-db: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint ratepipeline_pe-db_1 (6e649313e4cccd484d0672183cd24daf21c5e8ad3dc1e01fda57d0c942194b6d): Bind for 0.0.0.0:3306 failed: port is already allocated

ERROR: for pe-db  Cannot start service pe-db: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint ratepipeline_pe-db_1 (6e649313e4cccd484d0672183cd24daf21c5e8ad3dc1e01fda57d0c942194b6d): Bind for 0.0.0.0:3306 failed: port is already allocated
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

When checking what runs on port `3306` via:

```
sudo netstat -nlp | grep 3306
tcp6       0      0 :::3306                 :::*                    LISTEN      3042/docker-proxy
```

I see the docker-proxy. There is no other mysql database running locally. I can kill the `docker-proxy` via:

```
sudo killall docker-proxy
sudo netstat -nlp | grep 3306
```

and then I see nothing running on port `3306`. Yet `docker-compose up` will run into the same error again, claiming port is already in use even though `netstat` will show no user on the port.

I also tried restarting the docker daemon via

```
 sudo service docker restart
```

and rebooting my system. The issue persists.

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 8):

In my case, I did in fact have a mysql container running. It would not show on netstat, but I could see it via `docker ps`

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                       COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                                    NAMES

b59b7973d88b        mysql:5.7                   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   10 days ago         Up 8 seconds        0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp, 33060/tcp                                        squbsstub_db_1
```

I then could kill that container via its `CONTAINER ID`, in this case:

```
docker kill b59b7973d88b
```

Then my former docker-compose project would spin up fine.

Comment: I don't have any containers running! Any ideas?

Comment: @PetarVasilev Long shot: Maybe you have docker installed twice, once with snap and once the official way? Or you may have a local mysql server already listening on the port? Other then that I wouldn't know and you may best ask a follow-up question while linking to this one.

Comment: It was due to having MySQL running on that port. Stopped it and it started working.